# Nested IF & AND statement Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having trouble with a nested IF & AND statement, I'm sure that the problem is to do with the AND statements because my function is in the correct format.

I'm looking to Return a string based on the % of a table I have done AD38= 4%,AE38= 12%,AF38= 13%,AG38= 70%*

The above are formulas themselves but these are the results. The IF formula is below. I appreciate it's very long but I'm really banging my head against the wall.

```
IF(AND(AD38>AE38,AD38>AF38,AD38>AG38),CONCATENATE(AX31," customers age ",AD37," are the dominant age group"),

IF(AND(AE38>AD38,AE38>AF38,AF38>AG38),CONCATENATE(AX31," customers age ",AE37," are the dominant age group"),

IF(AND(AF38>AD38,AF38>AE38,AF38>AG38),CONCATENATE(AX31," customers age ",AF37," are the dominant age group"),

IF(AND(AG38>AD38,AG38>AE38,AG38>AG38),CONCATENATE(AX31," customers age ",AG37," are the dominant age group")))))
```

Any help is reaaaaally appreciated!

Comment: Just to give you a hint - search in google **alternative to multiple if statements excel**. The first page answers are quite good.

Answer (score 2):

It's really a bad idea to nest `IF`s. Lookup formulae (vlookup, hlookup, index/match, etc) are better when the information is structured. The solution I propose is the following:

```
=CONCATENATE(AX31," customers age ",INDEX(AD37:AG37,MATCH(MAX(AD38:AG38),AD38:AG38,0))," are the dominant age group")
```

Here, `INDEX(AD37:AG37,MATCH(MAX(AD38:AG38),AD38:AG38,0))` is in multiple parts, the innermost being `MAX(AD38:AG38)`, which gets the highest value from your 4 cells (in your example, 70%). `MATCH` looks for the position of this value (in your example, 4th cell), feeds it to `INDEX` so that it returns the matching cell (4th cell in the range AD37:AG37).

Comment: Great thank you for your help ! I thought MAX may have been a good solution but I didn't quite have the logic to put it together